# How can I change the text decoration on numbers only on my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a page here: http://joeltrauger.com/games that has some information about a game walkthrough I'm about to post and I was hoping to provide some information about the game on the page. The only problem is that when I load the page the numbers are displayed in a superscript. I cannot find out why or how they are doing this. As far as I can tell, there is no CSS or JavaScript controlling this. The site template I'm using comes from Rick Waalders [here](http://www.pixelsbyrick.com/).

#### Sample Code

```
<p>
    Shadow Man is a game originally released for PC, Nintendo 64, Sega Dreamcast, and Sony PlayStation in 1999. A sequel, Shadow Man: 2econd Coming, was released exclusively for PlayStation 2 in 2002. Shadow Man is copyrighted by Acclaim Studios and Acclaim Entertainment. <br /><br />
    Watch me play Shadow Man on PC:
</p>
```

#### Expected Output

Shadow Man is a game originally released for PC, Nintendo 64, Sega Dreamcast, and Sony PlayStation in 1999. A sequel, Shadow Man: 2econd Coming, was released exclusively for PlayStation 2 in 2002. Shadow Man is copyrighted by Acclaim Studios and Acclaim Entertainment.

Watch me play Shadow Man on PC:

#### Actual Output

[image: Web Page actual output]

[Link to web site](http://joeltrauger.com/games)

I am using Google Chrome as my browser on Windows 8.

Comment: Numbers look fine from here

Comment: Ditto. Fine in Chrome. Try disabling and extensions or addons, and clear your cache.

Comment: I'm seeing it. It's especially odd considering it's just setting the font to sans-serif

Comment: @j08691 I just disabled all extensions and cleared cache. No change.

Comment: You have font declaration error `font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";` in your SCSS

Comment: It seems to be the Arial font, I guess? When I set my default sans-serif to Tahoma it looks normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a CSS property `font-feature-settings` in the body that is affecting how numbers are displayed:

```
body {
    font-feature-settings: "kern" 1, "liga" 1, "frac" 1, "pnum" 1;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    ...
}
```

The `"frac" 1` portion of it enables automatic fractions, which is causing the numbers to superscript automatically. Use this definition instead, if you need that CSS property still:

```
font-feature-settings: "kern" 1, "liga" 1, "pnum" 1;
```

Also, there is an error in your CSS for the `font-family` properties. They are written as such:

```
font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
```

This needs to be

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: I can't see that `font-feature-settings` does anything to my webpage. It's only there because the template had it.

Comment: correction, you were right. removing that fixed it.

Comment: @JoelTrauger It's the "frac" setting, specifically.  Knocking that out in the debugger fixes it.

Comment: Yup, you were right. I just pushed the change to the website. It should appear properly now.